# Spring MVC usage of form:radiobuttons to bind data (whole object not only one value)

Tags: forms, jsp, spring-mvc, radio-button

I have a problem with sending data to backend by POST from my JSP using construction:

```
<form:radiobuttons path="pvClCategory" items="${categoryList}" itemLabel="clcaCategory"/>
```

After sumbit my Jboss (version 5) displays:

```
HTTP Status 400 - description: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().
```

I don't know how to see sent request. When I am using construction below everything works fine but I do not want to bind only one value from object, but whole object:

```
<form:radiobuttons path="pvClCategory.clcaCategory" items="${categoryList}" itemValue="clcaCategory" itemLabel="clcaCategory"/>
```

So, the first form construction (with binding whole object) cause me a problem. Form is initialised properly it means that radio options are correctly displayed and correct value is selected on jsp site. But problem appears when I want to submit the form, i receive error (HTTP Status 400 request sent by client was syntactically incorrect). Any idea why? What I am doing wrong?

---

### My code:

I have one entity class Violation with field named pvClCategory type of ClCategory

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PV_VIOLATIONS")
public class Violation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="VIOL_ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="VIOL_CLCA_ID")
    private ClCategory pvClCategory;

    /* others fields and getters/setters */
}
```

My ClCategory entity class which is needed to bind it to Violation.pvClCategory field:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PV_CL_CATEGORIES")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class ClCategory implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="CLCA_ID")
    private long clcaId;

    @Column(name="CLCA_CATEGORY")
    private String clcaCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pvClCategory")
    private List<Violation> pvViolations;

    public ClCategory() {
    }

    public long getClcaId() {
        return this.clcaId;
    }

    public void setClcaId(long clcaId) {
        this.clcaId = clcaId;
    }

    public String getClcaCategory() {
        return this.clcaCategory;
    }

    public void setClcaCategory(String clcaCategory) {
        this.clcaCategory = clcaCategory;
    }

    public List<Violation> getPvViolations() {
        return this.pvViolations;
    }

    public void setPvViolations(List<Violation> pvViolations) {
        this.pvViolations = pvViolations;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (clcaId ^ (clcaId >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ClCategory other = (ClCategory) obj;
        if (clcaId != other.clcaId)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

This Violation class is used in my form in commandName property as follows (file name: v.jsp):

```
<form:form action="../update" method="post" commandName="violation">
    <form:radiobuttons path="pvClCategory" items="${categoryList}" itemLabel="clcaCategory"/>
    <!-- other fields -->
    <button type="submit" value="Apply Changes" class="button-default" >Apply</button>
</form:form>
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/viol")
public class ViolationController {

    @RequestMapping("edit/{violationId}")
    public String edit(@PathVariable("violationId") long id, Map<String, Object> map) {
        Violation violation = violationService.getViolation(id);

        map.put("violation",violation);
        map.put("categoryList", adminService.listCategories());

        return "v";
    } 
}
```

As I understand in the construction **form:radiobuttons path="" items=""** the path is property for data binding so whole object from delivered list in items should be binded to it. I put in items List of my categories which are objects of type ClCategory. After submit error appears.

When i use **form:radiobuttons path="pvClCategory.clcaCategory" items="${categoryList}" itemValue="clcaCategory" itemLabel="clcaCategory"** to bind only String value from object in items (in both cases is used the same object list of type ClCategory) then the form is correctly submited but I do not want to bind only one value of objecte but whole object. Could you help me what am I doing wrong?